# data name as an argument passed in a function in R

Tags: r, function

I built an R package and include a dataset called `mouse` where I can access it using `data(mouse)`. In the package, I also have a function called `fun` which takes, as its first argument, the name of a dataset (included in the package):

```
fun = function(dt = NULL, ...) {
    data(dt)
    ...
    dt.sub = dt[ ,1:6]
    ...
}
```

However, when I use the function as `fun(dt = "mouse")`, it says `In data(dt) : data set ‘dt’ not found`. Also, I cannot use `dt[ ,1:6]` since `dt` here is a string. I tried to use `noquote` and `as.name` functions to get rid of the quotation marks, but the object `dt` does NOT refer to the mouse dataset.

My question is, what's the best approach to pass the name of a dataset (mouse in this case) in the function argument, and then use it in the function body? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you hard code the `data(mouse)` part? Are there any other data sets that need to make `fun` flexible in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f <- function(dt = NULL) {
  do.call("data", list(dt))
  dt <- eval(as.name(dt))
  head(dt)
}
```

Comment: Some commentary on *why* that's the way to do it would be helpful.